# Despite 'closest' what other options are there for layout plot in igraph in python?

Tags: python, layout, plot, igraph

I have looked exhaustively in documentation but I have not found other options rather than 'closest' for hovermode= option when using layout in python. Any help?

My drawing function is such: passing a graph (igraph.Graph())

```
import igraph 

def drawing_group(g, name='a'):
    layout = g.layout("fr")
    visual_style = {}
    visual_style["margin"] = 100
    visual_style['hovermode'] = 'closest'
    igraph.plot(g, 'g_%s.png' % (str(num) + name), **visual_style)
```

Thanks

Comment: @Támas the expert, where are you?

Comment: buried under work in my daytime job ;) What's `hovermode` by the way? I didn't even know that it existed and I wrote the Python interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of points here:

1. Your questions seems to be hill formulated. The hovermode exists
   in interactive plots produced by `plotly` and not by `igragh` itself.
2. `plotly` has `hovermode` that can either be "x", "y", "closest" or
   false.

refs:

https://plot.ly/python/3d-network-graph/
https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-scene-hovermode